# Renaming Item in a TreeCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to make a rename feature for a Treectrl.

Where, a TextCtrl goes over the element and I am able to rename it. I cant find this feature on the API but I am sure that there has to be some way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to rename tree elements (leaves), right? Well when you instantiate the TreeCtrl, give it the following style flags: wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.TR_EDIT_LABELS

Now you should be able to click or double-click any of the items and rename them. See the wxPython demo for more cool tricks.

Comment: I actually don't want to rename when it is double clicked but when something else happens. How can I do this?